# get output from two tables(table A and b) if column A from table A is equal to column B from Table B

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have two tables A and B, both tables have a column address.  Table A has id1 column and Table B has id2 column.  I would like to get the address column (it can be table B) if the values in id1 and id2 columns are the same. How can I do that in sql command?  It's worth to mention if these columns are the same, the addresses will be the same too or similar, so the address can be from either table. I'm very new to sql and your help will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: update your question show the schema of the tables ,, a proper data sample and the expected result ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
Select address 
from tablea as a, table b as b 
where b.id =a.id
```

Comment: Please stop using the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the where clause and start using an explicit `JOIN` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there's a chance that the address in table 1 is missing, otherwise it'd just be a matter of selecting that field. I added a case statement to handle that just in case (heh), but if not you can just replace that whole bit with a.address

```
Select a.id1, 
     case when a.address is not null 
        then a.address 
        else b.address end as new_address.
from Table1 A, Table2 B
where a.id1 = b.id2
```

Additionally, if you've got a combination of inner and outer joins happening (or just a lot of joins) then you'll want to add more explicit join criteria.

Comment: Please stop using the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the where clause and start using an explicit `JOIN` operator.

Comment: There's nothing fragile about an implicit join if it's used in the right place.  Join operators are only necessary if doing an outer join.

Comment: Implicit joins **are** fragile because it's easy to wind up with a cross join because a missing join condition will not lead to an error message. It's impossible to accidentally write a cross join with explicit JOIN operators. Look at this: http://hastebin.com/tayimobapo.sql and tell me how long you need to find out if there is a join condition missing or not.

Comment: That's what parenthesis and tabs are for.  

Also, like three seconds, the second address (adr) wasn't joined, despite the structure being unnecessarily confusing (If orders is the master table, then why not have it be the primary in all joins?)

The point is that there's not ONE way to do some things.  You're describing a preference that not everyone agrees on and has no impact on performance.  That being said, if you've got ten tables joined or a combination of inner and outer joins, then DEFINITELY use explicit joins.